# Applying conditions on the process of randomly picking up element

Tags: python, random, python-itertools

I need to pick 2 groups of  2 students don't talk the same language, without repetition. Each student only appears once.

I have this list

```
import random
from itertools import permutations
seq = [['Sham','Arabic'],['Amina', 'Arabic'], ['Bill', 'French'], ['Qing','Hindi']]
```

I need to pick 4 groups of  2 students don't talk the same language, without repetition.

I have implement this Function:

```
def group (x, y):
    res=[]
    #N = len(seq)
    for i in range( y):
        while len(res) < y:
            res = random.sample(x,k=y)
            while res[i][1] == res[i-1][1]:
                return group(x,y)
    return res
```

Then I apply these conditions to get the final results, the one students must appear in only one group:

```
final = []
for i in range(2):
    pick = group (seq, 2)

    if pick in final or pick[::-1]  in final:
        group(seq, 2)
        pass

    for i in pick:
        for j in i:
            if j  in final:
                group(seq, 2)
                pass
    else:
        final.append(pick)

print (final)
```

I am still getteing wrong results, the one student appear more than once.
expected results:

```
     [ [['Sham','Arabic'],['Qing','Hindi']],
 [['Bill', 'French'], ['Amina', 'Arabic']] ]
```

but what i get(sham existed twice):

```
[ [['Sham','Arabic'],['Qing','Hindi']],
 [['Bill', 'French'], ['Sham','Arabic']] ]
```

Comment: and the problem is...

Comment: still getteing wrong results, the one student appear more than once

Comment: when it makes the next pick up, it doesn't consider the previous ones. and it consider a completley new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't applied the condition correctly. Try this:

```
final = []
for i in range(4):
    pick = group (seq, 2)
    while pick in final or pick[::-1] in final:
        pick = group(seq, 2)
    final.append(pick)

print(final)
```

You need to keep picking until the new `pick` is not in `final`. This can be done using a while loop.

As I mentioned in the comment, there is no possibility of four groups satisfying the condition, but if you need two groups (as in your expected output) satisfying the conditions, here is the extra condition you need to apply:

```
picked = []
final = []
for i in range(2):
    pick = group (seq, 2)
    while pick in final or pick[::-1] in final or any(p in picked for p in pick):
        pick = group (seq, 2)
    final.append(pick)
    picked.extend(pick)

print(final)
```

You can use an additional list (`picked`) which holds the student-language pairs picked so far. Then keep picking until the new group has no pair from `picked`.

Comment: i think it is worked for the first condition, now no 2 groups the same but still the second condition. no one element inside one othe grops is existed before

Comment: I gave you the code snippet to show you what you were doing wrong. You are doing the same mistake with the second condition as well. I can give you the full code, but then there is no learning and that is not what stackoverflow is for. Try to understand how I fixed the first condition and fix your second condition in a similar manner.

Comment: ive done this and it doesnt work: for i in pp:
            for j in i:
                for k in rr:
                    for h in k:
                        while h == j:
                            pp = group(seq, 2)
                    
        else:
            rr.append(pp)

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, on the given input, the second condition will never satisfy. Can you give an expected output.

Comment: You said you need to pick four groups, but in your expected results you have shown only two.

Comment: this was in the orginal list, it is bigger than this one wich is just as an example..